# Bean values not updating in validation in jsf

Tags: jsf

I have a scenario where i have a form with fields mobile phone, home phone and office phone. each field has a corresponding radio button named preferred line. only one or the three radio is selectable. and when selected alone the field should be required. so i framed the code like below.

```
<table class="addaccount-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
border="0">
<tr>
    <td><label><h:outputText value="Home Phone" /></label></td>
    <td><h:inputText id="homePhone" maxlength="14"
            value="#{Controller.ContactPageBean.homePhone}"
            required="#{not empty Controller.ContactPageBean.homePhoneSelected}"
            requiredMessage="Preferred phone is required">
        </h:inputText> <br /> <h:message for="homePhone" style="color:red"></h:message></td>
    <td><h:selectOneRadio id="homePhoneSelectedId"
            styleClass="addacountradio"
            value="#{Controller.ContactPageBean.homePhoneSelected}">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="Home" itemLabel="Preferred" />
            <f:ajax render="homePhone" />
        </h:selectOneRadio></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label><h:outputText value="Office Phone" /></label></td>
    <td><h:inputText id="officePhone" maxlength="14"
            value="#{Controller.ContactPageBean.officePhone}"
            required="#{not empty Controller.ContactPageBean.officePhoneSelected}"
            requiredMessage="Preferred phone is required">
        </h:inputText> <br /> <h:message for="homePhone" style="color:red"></h:message></td>
    <td><h:selectOneRadio id="officePhoneSelectedId"
            styleClass="addacountradio"
            value="#{Controller.ContactPageBean.officePhoneSelected}">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="Home" itemLabel="Preferred" />
            <f:ajax render="officePhone" />
        </h:selectOneRadio></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label><h:outputText value="Mobile Phone" /></label></td>
    <td><h:inputText id="mobilePhone" maxlength="14"
            value="#{Controller.ContactPageBean.mobilePhone}"
            required="#{not empty Controller.ContactPageBean.mobilePhoneSelected}"
            requiredMessage="Preferred phone is required">
        </h:inputText> <br /> <h:message for="mobilePhone" style="color:red"></h:message></td>
    <td><h:selectOneRadio id="mobilePhoneSelectedId"
            styleClass="addacountradio"
            value="#{Controller.ContactPageBean.mobilePhoneSelected}">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="Home" itemLabel="Preferred" />
            <f:ajax render="mobilePhone" />
        </h:selectOneRadio></td>
</tr>
```

Now when i clicked the three radio button in row and submit i am getting required error message for the three fields. I expected only the error message which the radio button was currently selected. please help.

Comment: Required "scopes" to the form you're using. I've never played with it, but if you isolated the required components to a form it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You mistype h:message of officePhone as `<h:message for="homePhone" style="color:red">` while it should be `<h:message for="officePhone" style="color:red">` .

Also, I suggest you edit all `<f:selectItem itemValue="Home" itemLabel="Preferred" />` except homephone. For example `<f:selectItem itemValue="Office" itemLabel="Preferred" />`

I tried this and everything works, check this:

```
<h:form>
    <table class="addaccount-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
           border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label><h:outputText value="Home Phone" /></label>
            </td>
            <td><h:inputText id="homePhone" maxlength="14"
                             value="#{ContactPageBean.homePhone}"
                             required="#{not empty ContactPageBean.homePhoneSelected}"
                             requiredMessage="Home phone is required">
                </h:inputText> <br /> 
                <h:message for="homePhone" style="color:red"></h:message>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h:selectOneRadio id="homePhoneSelectedId"
                                  styleClass="addacountradio"
                                  value="#{ContactPageBean.homePhoneSelected}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="Home" itemLabel="Preferred" />
                    <f:ajax render="homePhone" />
                </h:selectOneRadio>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label><h:outputText value="Office Phone" /></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h:inputText id="officePhone" maxlength="14"
                             value="#{ContactPageBean.officePhone}"
                             required="#{not empty ContactPageBean.officePhoneSelected}"
                             requiredMessage="Office phone is required">
                </h:inputText> <br /> 
                <h:message for="officePhone" style="color:red"></h:message>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h:selectOneRadio id="officePhoneSelectedId"
                                  styleClass="addacountradio"
                                  value="#{ContactPageBean.officePhoneSelected}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="Office" itemLabel="Preferred" />
                    <f:ajax render="officePhone" />
                </h:selectOneRadio>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label><h:outputText value="Mobile Phone" /></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h:inputText id="mobilePhone" maxlength="14"
                             value="#{ContactPageBean.mobilePhone}"
                             required="#{not empty ContactPageBean.mobilePhoneSelected}"
                             requiredMessage="Mobile phone is required">
                </h:inputText> <br /> 
                <h:message for="mobilePhone" style="color:red"></h:message>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h:selectOneRadio id="mobilePhoneSelectedId"
                                  styleClass="addacountradio"
                                  value="#{ContactPageBean.mobilePhoneSelected}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="Mobile" itemLabel="Preferred" />
                    <f:ajax render="mobilePhone" />
                </h:selectOneRadio>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{ContactPageBean.doSome()}"/>
        </h:form>
```

I changed `Controller.ContactPageBean` as `ContactPageBean` for simplicity.
Finally, maybe it's better to use checkbox instead of radioButton,isn't it?